# Run sql script from bat file (oracle, batch)

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have **bat** script:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=X.Y.Z.F)(Port=1521))
                               (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=some_sid))) @test.sql
goto end

:end
pause 0
```

and my **test.sql**

```
DECLARE
test varchar2(32000);
BEGIN
  test:='value';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('string test');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test||' test');
END;
```

When I run it I got this:

[image]

What it means?

Comment: Unless it's executed automatically by your setup, you'll also need to do a `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before your `DECLARE` statement in order to show the output from DBMS_OUTPUT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enter a forward slash (/) to flush the buffer.

```
DECLARE
test varchar2(32000);
BEGIN
  test:='value';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('string test');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test||' test');
END;
/   <<<<<<<<<<<<<----- forward slash
```

Comment: You bet!  Note that I added a comment to the original post as well.

Comment: Yeap.  / is all you need.